# Why my Java heap is with so many char[]

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, memory-leaks

I have a web application in Tomcat where I do many String operations (substring, indexof, trimming, etc.). I made a heap dump with jmap and I loaded it using VisualVM and I realized that near 50% of my heap memory usage is with char[],
Why the char[] are taking that memory usage?, should I be concerned?, is it something related to String pools?[image]

Comment: Can we see some of the code? It looks like you're using a large number of String(s) - have you checked what the results are after a `gc()`?

Comment: Things like this: return tiempo.replace("años", "").replace("año", "")
                .replace("meses", "").replace("mes", "")
                .replace("semanas", "").replace("semana", "")
                .replace("dias", "").replace("dia", "").trim();

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli That'll create a lot of temporary objects that go out of scope immediately. There's no memory leak there, the garbage collector just hasn't gotten around to cleaning them up yet.

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli From the screenshot we can see that you have a lot of hash map entries. Are you storing your strings into a map?

Comment: @Andrey Chaschev, No, for this class I'm not using HashMaps for saving the strings

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli Ok, so you also have 200k of hash map entries. Do you have an idea of what could be stored there? This could be causing a memory leak... May be at some step of your processing you put your strings into a map?

Comment: @Andrey Chaschev For other class I'm having near 4000 keys in a HashMap, but is something to be concerned?, I'm asumming that the GC will do its work.

Comment: This dump shows that there are 30k HashMaps containing 200k entries in total, which presumably contain 800k strings. And they are NOT GC-ed. So there must be something which references all this data and stops it from being GC-ed. You might need to analyze an object graph to check what's holding them. As far as I know, JVisualVM has this feature.

Answer (score 9):

Strings are internally just a char[] and some extra data. A char[] means a character array in other words it's an array that saves your string character by character. If you do a lot of string proccessing it's entirely possible that your system is fileld with char arrays.

So in short nothing to be concerned unless you system is actually using more memory then it should be. In that case you can look if there are some file structures left uncleared (hash maps or related).

Comment: Note that the profiler only shows about 90M in use; that's not much at all, and the garbage collector probably just isn't interested enough to clean them up yet.

Comment: So are that char[]s eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: char[]s can be collected if you are done using them. The question is do you have an estimate of how many string should be inside your system? If you expect there to be in the order of 1000 strings and you have 100 000+ then something is wrong however if you expect there to be so many then something is wrong. So how many strings do you esitmate to be there?

Answer (score 3):

811k of `char[]` correspond to 800k of `String`s, so yes, you have too many Strings.

If you're having a memory leak (judging by the tag), then it's most probably are strings in a `HashMap`. You have 800k instances of strings, 200k instances of hash entries, 30k of maps. This  probably means that your strings are kept in this cache and are not removed. Global map is a frequent cause of memory leaks, one needs to make sure that they are evicted from this cache.

Since all these values are not being GC-ed, you could try analyzing an object graph to see what's holding them with a tool like [JProfiler](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/views/heapwalker/heapwalker.html).

Comment: 800k is not that much. How do you quantify "too many Strings"?

Comment: @SteveKuo by Nestor having problems with this only. :-) This could be a dump of a state when it's not yet OOM, but soon will be. My answer is a guess, it's just I have seen many such cases, that I'm confident with it.